# Filtering list with another list PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, linq, powershell

Coming from a C# background and being a complete PowerShell novice, I am trying to make a simple filtering based on two lists/arrays.

Goal: filter elements of list 'toFilter' based on list 'filter', so to only keep elements of 'toFilter', which are matching at least one of the patterns listed in 'filter'.

Ideally I would like to achieve that using piping or Linq (and not nested loops).

In C#, I would do it like this:

```
string[] filter  = {"A", "B", "C"};
string[] toFilter = {"AA", "AB", "DD"};

var filtered = toFilter.Where(s1 => filter.Any(s2 => s1.Contains(s2))).ToList();
```

or even shorther, using method groups:

```
var filtered = toFilter.Where(s1 => filter.Any(s1.Contains)).ToList();
```

With the expected outcome of:

```
AA AB
```

For Powershell, I found [an article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/high-performance-powershell-linq) which describes powershell equivalents of Linq in C#, but apparently I cannot grasp the syntax.

I came with a following solution:

```
$filter = @("A", "B", "C")
$toFilter = @("AA", "AB", "DD")

$filtered = $toFilter | where {[Linq.Enumerable]::Any([string[]]$filter, [Func[string,bool]]{ $_ -match $args[0] })}
```

But it results in an empty list.

What would be a correct way of using those two arrays to come with an expected result?

EDIT:
Apparently my solution works, but it is not pure LINQ, so a question is still valid.

Comment: i've seen that article. i feel really stupid reading it :) i wonder if someone could help

Comment: What version of PowerShell do you have? Your syntax looks flawed but actually generated the correct output for me on v5

Comment: @Matt Funnily enough it has worked for me today, despite seeing empty output yesterday. I guess it might have something to do with re-assigning variables in the Windows Powershell interactive window.

I am running v 5.1.

Answer (score 5):

The reason your example fails is that `$_` and `$args[0]` refer to the same thing in the inner delegate.

There's no need to employ LINQ here though - you can do the same with a nested `Where-Object` clause:

```
$filter = @("A", "B", "C")
$toFilter = @("AA", "AB", "DD")

$filtered = $toFilter | Where-Object {
    $item = $_
    @($filter |Where-Object {$item.Contains($_)}).Count -gt 0
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice and readable solution, the only drawback I see is introducing an extra variable.

BTW, I have run my solution today and strangely it works, so it seems that my reasoning was correct and  '$args[0]' responds to elements passed in from 'filter' and the pipe variable '$_' is representing the values of 'toFilter' which is piped in - it does not change because of being inside of the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Cards on the table this is my first day working with LINQ. It seems like something I would like to be able to use. I tried to nest LINQ statements as best I could to try and get the right results using only LINQ.

```
[Linq.Enumerable]::where(
    $toFilter,
    [System.Func[System.Object,bool]]{ 
        param($filterItem)
        [Linq.Enumerable]::Any(
            $filter, 
            [Func[System.Object,bool]]{
                param($singlefilter) 
                # write-host "$filterItem -match $singlefilter"
                $filterItem -match $singlefilter}
        )
    }
)
```

`Where` to work over `$toFilter` and the `Any` checks each `$filter` against each `$toFilter` item.

Comment: This is pure LINQ-esque, nicely done. But seeing all the extra syntax I can see why LINQ in PowerShell is not so popular comparing to "normal" piping and where clauses.

Comment: 100 percent agreed. However if you are looking for performance this still has a place